# Find the distribution of w

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution

Suppose that X = N(0,1) and Y = N(1,1), and assume that X and Y are independent.
Determine the distribution of W = X - 2Y .

Comment: It's preferable if you ask a question about the concepts that are giving you trouble rather than just pasting in the assignment.

Comment: hey jonsca, no im studying for my final in 2 days...so i tried using method of transformations and method of moment generating functions....but i do not think those will work.  So i am thinking I have to integrate using CDFs but I do not know how to set it up.

Comment: answer is W~N(-2,5) if anyone cares but i do not know how to get it.

Answer (score 8):

Here are some hints.  I am sure you would have been taught these somewhere.  It is much simpler than the methods you are considering.

First, if W=X-2Y, what do you get if you plug the means of X and Y into that equation?

Secondly, if you multiply a random variable by a constant, the variance of the new random variable is going to be the original variance multiplied by that constant, squared.

Thirdly, if you then take two independent random variables and add them together, the the variance of the sums is the sum of the variance.

Comment: But, since the _distribution_ of $X-2Y$ is wanted, not just the mean and variance, you need a Fourthly, a weighted linear sum $\sum_i a_iX_i$ of independent normal random variables is anormal random variable with mean $\sum_i a_i\mu_i$ and variance  $\sum_i a_i^2\sigma_i^2$ as an additional hint.